# jQuery Script works in all browsers but Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

[This site](http://www.bostonteaclub.com/en/our-stores) has a script that works in all browsers I tested but Chrome, which I think is strange because it is usually IE that acts up. What should happen is that there is a dynamic tour through the store, in Chrome only the picture is seen, it seems like none of the script triggered.

The error console says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'set'
```

however I don't know what to do with this information. Any ideas?
I am using Chrome 4.0.249.78

again [here is the link](http://www.bostonteaclub.com/en/our-stores)

Comment: Try posting the jQuery you're using.

Comment: it's all there, it's to much to just post all of it....

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link. I'm not getting any errors in Chrome.

Comment: I got the same error while using `jquery-1.4.2.min.js`.
I have updated to `jquery-1.4.3.min.js` and it got resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first line, but the second one is coming out of mootools (line 23), and is actually being reported by FireFox as well. If memory serves it's because of incompatibilities between mootools and jquery.

Comment: For future reference, the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined` error does not appear to be directly related to mootools. I get this error while including the latest remote copy `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` but not when loading a local copy. This was run from a local network apache server. When copied to my desktop, the error is not raised. Something's amiss, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of MooTools, but for anyone who may be new to these issues, you will need to add the jQuery.noConflict(); to your javascript.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: This is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solve it by downloading the latest copy jquery-1.5.1.min.js
try that!!